# How to stop replacing at first specific character

Tags: php, preg-replace, design-patterns

I want to hide specific tags, till the closing tag in some content, but I can't get it to work properly.
This is what I have:

```
$fnc_patterns   =   "/\[display=[^!]+\]?.*\[\/display=[^!]+\]/";
$str           =    preg_replace($fnc_patterns, '', $str);

$str = "Dummy text text dummy [display=hide]hide this[/display=hide] but it also [display=no_hide]hides this[/display=no_hide] and not [display=hide]this[/display=hide] :(!";
//Outputs: Dummy text text dummy :(!
```

But it should output `Dummy text text dummy but it also hides this :(!`
I replace `[display=no_hide]` and closing tage before this function. The thing is, it simply replaces everything between `[display=XXX]` and `[/display=XXX]` but it should stop at the first closing tag encounter. How can I do that?

(Note that `XXX` can be everything and not only `hide` or `no_hide`)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can your tags be nested? example : `[abc]xyz[abc]xyz[/abc][/abc]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point! Yes they should :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I forgot to add: the tag is alwasy unique, so the first [abc] tag would close at the first [/abc] ending tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. It searches from `display:someword` or `display=someword` to the next matching ending tag. I use the "reluctant match" operator `*?` to ensure that it doesn't go from the first open tag to the last close tag.

```
$fnc_patterns   =   "/(\[display[=:]([^\]]+)\].*?\[\/display[=:]\2\])/"
```

Comment: Oh darn it, the `:` instead of `=` were typos, sorry! Sounds good! But what if `hide` is constantly changed? `hide` is just an example. It shouldn't always be hidden!

Comment: well, you probably don't want to hide all tags. So you will have to give some range of values it could be.. or if you want to make it dynamic then just replace "hide" with a variable.

Comment: I meant that it could be everything, `[display=dog]`, `[display=cat]` or `[display=alligator]`. Is that possible?

Comment: well obviously it can't be no_hide.  So I could make it everything but no_hide? or it could be a variable.. really depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: `hide` and `no_hide` were just examples. I won't literally use those variables. I'm trying to hide everything from the starting tag, to the corresponding closing tag. So if it says `[display=dog]` it should replace everything untill the first `[/display=dog]`.

Comment: Try what i just edited the answer to.  It now searches from an entire word to the tag closing that word

Comment: thanks, removed the additional ")".  It works for me on a variety of different test cases. http://rubular.com/. http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: It indeed works on rubular, but it doesn't actually replace in PHP. How can that be?

Comment: I also saw it worked on solmetra, but it really doesn't do anything when I try it out.. Could it be the PHP version?

Comment: That is very odd.  It might be the PHP version. Which version do you have?

Comment: I'm running version 5.4.7, would be really strange if it is because of the version.

Comment: okay the problem is solved.. The problem was that I used `"` instead of `'` when assigning `$fnc_pattern`... Never knew that mattered! Thanks!

Comment: Now I have the problem that when there is a new line, it doesn't replace. Do you know what regex I have to use to accept replace even those? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? like the tag needs to be matched over multiple strings? The one I gave you should work for tags that are at the end of the line(right before the newline)

Comment: Yes, but when it's like `[display=someword](newline)asdadsad[/display=someword]` it doesn't work

Comment: It's working for me with newline characters. Give me a sample string it doesn't match.

Comment: If you take my code, for example, and simply press enter after an opening tag `[display=hide']-HERE-`. It won't work, here is an example `http://ideone.com/wkU3nb`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending greedybuddha's answer, if you also want to hide `[display=no_hide]hides this[/display=no_hide]`, use this:

```
(\[display[=:][no_]*hide\].*?\[\/display[=:][no_]*hide\])
```

Example: http://www.debuggex.com/embed/KRhwg3S-_8jnwQfG

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily select which tags you want to hide, you can use the *DEFINE* syntax. This pattern can deal with nested tags.

```
$str = <<<LOD
Shw1 [display=marmot]Hid1[/display=marmot]Shw2
[display=nutria]Hid2[display=badger]Hid3[/display=badger]Hid4[/display=nutria]
[display=marmot]Hid5[display=marmot]Hid6[/display=marmot]Hid7[/display=marmot]
Shw3 [display=weasel]Shw4[/display=weasel]
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
    # definitions
    (?(DEFINE)(?<terms>(?>nutria|marmot|badger)))

    # pattern
    \[display([=:]\g<terms>)]
        (?>[^][]++|(?R)?)+
    \[/display\2]
~x
LOD;

echo preg_replace ($pattern, '', $str);
```

Note that you can do the same without the *DEFINE* syntax:

```
$hidden_tags = array('nutria', 'marmot', 'badger');
$terms = implode('|', $hidden_tags);
$pattern = '~\[display([=:](?>'.$terms.')](?>[^][]++|(?R)?)+\[/display\1]~';
```